# Simple Multiple RX/TX SoftwareSerial?

Tags: serial, esp8266, softwareserial, arduino-leonardo, uart

In this project I will be using multiple ESP8266 WiFi modules (4) connected by software serial to an Arduino Leonardo Micro (1 UART). I plan to rotate between all 4 (starting with 2): Open port, write, read response, close port, move on....

This is a very barebones version of my code to address this one issue. Works flawlessly with a single (always open) connection, but it does not work when I close Ser1 (even if I don't start Ser2!!!)
Is the xxxx.end(); command broken or something?
Or am I doing something wrong? :/

Note: This code sends "AT" to the module, it responds with "OK"

When adding Ser2, LED flashes on Arduino periodically indicating it is writing to serial monitor, but nothing appears...

Code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial Ser1(10, 8);
SoftwareSerial Ser2(16, 7);
SoftwareSerial Ser3(14, 4);
SoftwareSerial Ser4(15, 2);
//Set up (RX, TX) pins^

void setup() {

  pinMode(10, INPUT);
  pinMode(16, INPUT);
  pinMode(14, INPUT);
  pinMode(15, INPUT);
  pinMode(8, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(7, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  //Set up Serial Monitor on host computer

}

void loop()
{

  delay(1000);

  Ser1.begin(9600); // open Ser1

  Ser1.write( 'A' );
  Ser1.write( 'T' );
  Ser1.write( '\r' );
  Ser1.write( '\n' );   // sends the line: "AT" with appropriate format

  Ser1.listen(); // make sure it's listening

  while ((Ser1.available() > 0)) { //Read entire string
    Serial.write(Ser1.read()); //Dump it to serial monitor
  }

  //Should Respond with "OK"

  Ser1.end(); //close Ser1 port
  //This breaks the code for some reason....

  Serial.println(); // Extra line in Serial Monitor for neatness


  Ser2.begin(9600); // open Ser2

  Ser2.write( 'A' );
  Ser2.write( 'T' );
  Ser2.write( '\r' );
  Ser2.write( '\n' );

  Ser2.listen();

  while ((Ser2.available() > 0)) {
    Serial.write(Ser2.read());
  }

  Ser2.end();

}
```

Comment: Why are you beginning and ending the object each time instead of just beginning once?

Comment: @Ignacio,  Software serial is only capable of one connection at a time, so it must be closed before I switch to a different port. Problem is my attempt to close it breaks the code. :(

Comment: No, it is capable of only *receiving* on one connection at a time.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Do you suggest beginning them all in setup? Then how can I switch the receiving from port to port?

Comment: Exactly how you already are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ignacio mentions, you should not be stopping and starting the serial ports. Instead just switch between them with `.listen()`:

> Enables the selected software serial port to listen. Only one software serial port can listen at a time; data that arrives for other ports will be discarded. Any data already received is discarded during the call to listen() (unless the given instance is already listening).
>
> [SoftwareSerial::listen() Manual Page](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerialListen)

So your code would be written as:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial Ser1(10, 8);
SoftwareSerial Ser2(16, 7);
SoftwareSerial Ser3(14, 4);
SoftwareSerial Ser4(15, 2);
//Set up (RX, TX) pins^

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Ser1.begin(9600); // open Ser1
  Ser2.begin(9600); // open Ser2    
}

void loop()
{

  delay(1000);

  Ser1.listen(); // Select Ser1 for receiving
  Ser1.print(F("AT\r\n"));     

  delay(1000); // Give it time to send a response or you'll get nothing!

  while ((Ser1.available() > 0)) { //Read entire string
    Serial.write(Ser1.read()); //Dump it to serial monitor
  }

  //Should Respond with "OK"

  Serial.println(); // Extra line in Serial Monitor for neatness

  Ser2.listen(); // Select Ser2 for receiving
  Ser2.print(F("AT\r\n"));

  delay(1000); // Give it time to send a response or you'll get nothing!

  while ((Ser2.available() > 0)) {
    Serial.write(Ser2.read());
  }    
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate how you fixed my problem AND optimised my code at the same time!! I think the main issue was not waiting for a response (I tried your fix lol). Amazing work!!