# Interconnected Arduinos via digital pins and magnets

Tags: arduino-nano

Before i get too far into the design phase of a project i have in mind, is there a way to connect arduinos in a non-master/slave manner to pass a few different combinations of HIGH/LOW (say 5) or 'information' both ways using digital pins? Perhaps some library i don't know about?

Each of these modules should be identical and be able to connect on any face to any other module. I've included a crude image of what I would like to accomplish.

[image: magnet modules]

I've already determined that i can solder to these neodymium magnets without loss of magnetic properties by having the little magnets attached to a stronger magnet during the soldering process. Magnet to magnet connection shows only a very tiny resistance.

If it can't be accomplished, i will need to abandon the project and look for some other means to make my project. Thanks in advance!

~zen

Comment: would serial connections work for you?

Comment: As long as i was only communicating to one face of the module at a time, but my understanding of the Tx/Rx communications would push out the command to all modules. I only want to send/receive to one module, not all of them at the same time.

Comment: you have more than one serial interface - some arduinos have 4 hardware serial interfaces (if I recall) ... then there's SoftwareSerial - to make any pair of pins a "serial" interface

Comment: Hmmm... since the rest of the project is only LED lighting with not much programming, I was hoping to use a cheap, low-power (usually 1 serial interface) arduino like the lilypad or similar. I would be creating some 30-40 modules to interact and so the cost of each is thusly multiplied.

Comment: Does 'SoftwareSerial' allow multiple Tx/Rx pin sets? That does look promising!

Comment: so, your wiring shows each "arduino" using 3 pairs of wires to connect to an adjacent "arduino" - so, how did you envisage these wires would be used for "communication"

Comment: I would need them to transmit or receive a value such as 1 for green, 2 for red, 3 for blue or something similar. Decision-making by the arduino would determine if that value was passed to another face. (It's sounding weirder and weirder).

Comment: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/43118/simple-multiple-rx-tx-softwareserial shows 4 software serial in use

Comment: by the way, I'd wire it differently ... if 1 is output and 2 is input, for example, then you'd need, for example 1 on top of 2 on the left of the board, and 2 on top of 1 on the right ... therefore, output connects to input and vice versa :p

Comment: Sweet! That looks like maybe the ticket. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: don't use high speeds though ... but it looks like you won't need to - I believe 9600 would work

Comment: Well, dang. I would need each of the modules and their faces to be identical as far as wiring, meaning that any face to be magnetically attached to any face. You're right, i can't connect Tx to Tx if i expect to read anything...

Comment: Yes, 9600 would be quick enough...

Comment: Hmmm... so maybe i need to use 4 pins for each side to be able to communicate back and forth serially? My mind's boggling a little.

Comment: not sure why you'd need 4 - the key is rotational symmetry

Comment: Oh, wait. Yes. If i have the Tx pin on the left and the Rx on the right, the two match each other's Rx and Tx. Sorry, i got confused. 

Thanks so much for your help and for having to suffer through my confusion!

Comment: upvote for a cool idea ..... i would give you another upvote, if i could, for including the information about soldering the magnets

Comment: @jsotola - I'll upvote for you :p

Comment: there is also an issue with magnet polarity ..... the Rx could me a magnet ... the Tx would be a plain metal contact .... the power pins would have to be pogo pins ... otherwise you would not get rotational symmetry

Comment: How would pogo pins help rotational symmetry @jsotola? There is a way to get rotational symmetry with the power though https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipOuhzEuYNfLFVrEynOVZ015yysy5AGGHLprJbm-S2iH80RgSi98F5woS5yH6yDZmA?key=R01LaERCM3huNExpX1lWeEpmWV9MT3pkOURNRzVR

Comment: @JaromandaX, i was unclear in my statement .... i was referring to the vertical layout of the power pins with the data pins on either side

Answer (score 1):

While idea looks cool, you need some kind of "locks" because not "any combination" can work.

Rotate second Arduino in bottom row on 180 degree and you will see that GND/5V reversed relatively to first arduino in second row.

You have to account magnet N-S polarities to allow good lock. Probably you can use magnet polarities to achieve proper orientation.

Answer (score -1):

Non-master/Slave is absolutely the best for lots of applications.
Why bother with Arduinos? There are much better processors available at low cost.
Lots of the STM32 processors allow you to address the serial ports.
For instance, from the reference manual of the popular STM32F103 (Blue pill).Quote.
Address mark detection (WAKE=1)
In this mode, bytes are recognized as addresses if their MSB is a ‘1’ else they are 
considered as data. In an address byte, the address of the targeted receiver is put on the 4 
LSB. This 4-bit word is compared by the receiver with its own address which is programmed 
in the ADD bits in the USART_CR2 register.
The USART enters mute mode when an address character is received which does not 
match its programmed address. In this case, the RWU bit is set by hardware. The RXNE 
flag is not set for this address byte and no interrupt nor DMA request is issued as the 
USART would have entered mute mode. Unquote.
Then use the Embitz compiler, free, use C or C++ if you have to.
C++ cannot compete with C for embedded work, proven over and over comparing code size and operating speed. Why use a processor without decent debugger?
Embitz and STM32 will give you an unbeatable debugger.
The larger STM32 processors also have Canbus, which is the ultimate non-master/slave.
Canbus is not difficult to set up, and you will never look back.
Alternatively, use ESP32 and Canbus.
Regards
Johan Smit