# Multiple SoftwareSerial's at the same time?

Tags: arduino-uno, softwareserial

I need to receive some data from USB and send it to the Android device via Bluetooth. The problem is that multiple SoftwareSerials won't connect at the same time.

Here is my code:

```
SoftwareSerial bluetooth(2,3);
SoftwareSerial usbConverter(4, 5);

void setup() {
  usbConverter.begin(9600);
  bluetooth.begin(9600);
  checkConnection();
}

void checkConnection() {
  while(true) {
    int areBothDevicesConnected = 0;
    if(bluetooth.available()) {
      areBothDevicesConnected++;
      bluetooth.println("Bluetooth connected");
      if(usbConverter.available()) {
        areBothDevicesConnected++;
        bluetooth.println("USB converter connected");
      } else {
        bluetooth.println("USB converter is not available");
      }
    }
    if(areBothDevicesConnected == 2) {
      bluetooth.println("All devices connected");
      break;
    }
    delay(2000);
  }
}
```

As far as I understand only one SoftwareSerial can listen at the same time but in my case, I can't even connect both devices. On Android device I always receive `USB converter is not available`.

My setup:

- Arduino UNO.
- HC-05 Bluetooth.
- USB to TTL converter.

Any clue?

Comment: `receive some data from USB` ... why are you not using  hardware serial for this?

Comment: `Any clue?` is not a question about arduino

Comment: I think you misunderstand what `SoftwareSerial.available()` does. It does not say anything about if the serial port is connected. It returns the number of received bytes in the buffer. When you don't send anything over the interfaces to the Arduino it will always return `0` aka false. Though - as you yourself already mentioned - you cannot receive on two `SoftwareSerial` interfaces at the same time, so your logic cannot ever work. Use hardware serial for one of the interfaces and rethink your connection check

Comment: When you have multiple instances of SoftwareSerial, you need to setup the `.listen()` method to switch between the instances if you are going to read from them. See https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/43125/40646

Comment: Thank you. That is what I needed!